# Einstein Bot License and Access Doubt

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot

I had a requirement of setting up Einstein Chatbot for various storefronts and I had few questions which as posted as below:

1. If a Einstein Chatbot is placed on various storefronts (CloudCraze/B2B Commerce), will it count as multiple licenses being consumed?
   How many concurrent sessions can run on a single chat license?
2. If we're using an Apex class to fetch a field (using SOQL) to be shown as a reply on the chatbot and assuming that the user doesn't have access to that particular object or field, would he still be able to see the data stored in the field that was fetched fetched?